# Ag-Grid - Alternative to the nonexisting event that is fired after ag-grid is fully loaded (including data load, filter, sort, column changes, etc)

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have to run a piece of code after the grid data has loaded, and sort, filter, column changes are applied.

As I understand [there is no such event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59313221/ag-grid-angular-firstdatarendered-does-not-fire) that is fired after ag-grid is loaded.

[gridReady/rowDataChanged](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/1602) does not work in my case, because onSortChanged/ onFilterChanged fires after that.

Is there any workaround? Any pointers on this issue would be helpful. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: `firstDataRendered` *gets fired the first time data is rendered into the grid.* can you elaborate with code piece what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: yeah, got it working using firstDataRendered. Thanks! :)